# Sorting a pointer Array.

Tags: c++, sorting, pointers

I have the following function below which takes in a pointer Array, and a size. It then sorts the strings in the array alphabetically.

However, every time I run the function in my main function, my program crashes. What could be wrong in my code?

```
int main()
{
    int size = 3;
    string *myList= new string[size];
    myList[0] = "Hello";
    myList[1] = "What's your name";
    myList[2] = "How are you?";
    arrSelectSort(&myList, size);

    return 0;
}
void arrSelectSort(string *arr[], int size)
{
    int startScan, minIndex;
    string *minElem = nullptr;
    for (startScan = 0; startScan < (size - 1); startScan++) {
        minIndex = startScan;
        minElem = arr[startScan];
        for (int index = startScan + 1; index < size; index++) {
            if (*(arr[index]) < *minElem) {
                minElem = arr[index];
                minIndex = index;
            }
        }
        arr[minIndex] = arr[startScan];
        arr[startScan] = minElem;
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't have a pointer array.

Comment: What do you mean? Isn't myList a pointer Array itself?

Comment: No, myList is a pointer to a string array.

Comment: @user3577478 `myList` is a pointer. It points to the first element of an array of `string` (which I am guessing is `std::string` but can't say for sure, given the incomplete code you posted.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
minElem = arr[startScan];
minElem = arr[index];
```

The above code implies that you have an array of pointers,which you don't. What you have is an a array of of strings pointed to by `string *myList`, and you passed the address of this single(and not an array) pointer to the function.

[image]

So you only have one pointer(`myList`) pointing to a memory location where an array of strings are stored, saying something like `string* arr[]=&myList;` and `arr[index];` in a loop will eventually(when `index>0`) access a value from a memory location which contain a garbage data(not a valid pointer) and trying to deference it will cause an error.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working code

```
#include<cstdio>
#include<string>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

void arrSelectSort(string *arr, int size)
{
    int startScan, minIndex;
    string minElem;
    for (startScan = 0; startScan < (size - 1); startScan++) {
        minIndex = startScan;
        minElem = arr[startScan];
        for (int index = startScan + 1; index < size; index++) {
            if (arr[index] < minElem) {
                minElem = arr[index];
                minIndex = index;
            }
        }
        arr[minIndex] = arr[startScan];
        arr[startScan] = minElem;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int size = 3;
    string *myList= new string[size];
    myList[0] = "Hello";
    myList[1] = "What's your name";
    myList[2] = "How are you?";
    arrSelectSort(myList, size);

    for(int i=0;i<size;i++) {
        cout << myList[i] << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

- Parameter of `arrSelectSort` function is using : `string *arr`. It is beacuse you want to sort pointer of string. By using `*arr[]` means you want to sort pointer of (array of string)
- `minElem` is only `string` datatype . `minElem` will contain string that pointed by `arr`, so it only a `string`, not pointer of `string`
- Comparison is only : `if (arr[index] < minElem)` . To access string that pointed by `arr`, we can access it like an array of `arr`
- Call the function : `arrSelectSort(myList, size);` . Parameter of `arrSelectSort` function is changed to `*arr`.